# Mysterious glitch in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory

My app/game has gone live in the App Store two days ago. Now I'm getting reports of a mysterious glitch that occurs when several levels have been completed (it's a puzzle game). The screen just gets black, no user interaction is possible anymore at all.

I think what happens is that my view gets deallocated, so the only thing that's left is my window, which has a black background.

At first I thought this could be due to a memory warning to which my view controller responds by releasing the view. But when I simulate memory warnings on the Simulator, everythings goes fine.

I have tested my app extensively using Instruments. It contains no memory leaks. It is using a constant ~43MB during gameplay. CPU load is low.

I'm quite clueless here. It's frustrating that I cannot reproduce the problem myself. I can't count the levels I've played myself anymore, trying to get this glitch to occur. Anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> But when I simulate memory warnings on the Simulator, everythings goes fine.

Did you try to simulate it on a real device with instruments? Did you try with older device models like 3g, 3gs?

Comment: yes, this is a good point, because 43 MB is quite a lot, especially for a 3g or older iPod Touch

Comment: How can I do that? Google wasn't really helpful on this one. Also, do you think this is useful? Shouldn't I get the same behavior in the Simulator with the simulated memory warning anyway?